# Issue in loading children eagerly

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using NHibernate with FluentNH.

Here are the four classes.

**FormType**

```
  public class FormType
  {
    public virtual int Id
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name
    { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<KeyCompetency> KeyCompetencies 
    { get; set; }
  }
```

**KeyCompetency**

```
  public class KeyCompetency
  {
    public virtual int Id
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name
    { get; set; }

    public virtual FormType FormType
    { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<SubCompetency> SubCompetencies 
    { get; set; }
  }
```

**SubCompetency**

```
  public class SubCompetency
  {
    public virtual int Id
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string Name
    { get; set; }    


    public virtual KeyCompetency KeyCompetency
    { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Ability> Abilities 
    { get; set; }
  }
```

**Ability**

```
  public class Ability
  {
    public virtual int Id
    { get; set; }

    public virtual string Description
    { get; set; }

    public virtual SubCompetency SubCompetency
    { get; set; }
  }
```

I'm trying to load a formtype based on id.

```
using (var session = DataContext.OpenSession())
{
    return session.Query<FormType>()
                  .Where(x => x.Id == 1)
                  .FetchMany(x => x.KeyCompetencies)
                  .ThenFetchMany(x => x.SubCompetencies)
                  .ThenFetchMany(x => x.Abilities)
                  .ToList().FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I'm getting duplicate records for key-competencies, sub-competencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map the collections as `Set` to avoid this problem. See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6194734/nhibernate-thenfetchmany-is-retrieving-duplicate-children). Also, since you're selecting by identity it's better to use `.SingleOrDefault` instead of `FirstOrDefault`.