# NHibernate Map by Code duplicates list items on one to many relation

Tags: c#, nhibernate, orm

The parent class:

```
public class Group
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual byte[] Icon { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Category> Categories { get; set; }
}
```

The child class:

```
public class Category
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Group Group { get; set; }
}
```

The mappings:

```
public CategoryMapping()
{
    this.Table("[Category]");
    this.Schema("[RSS]");
    this.Id(x => x.Id, e => e.Generator(Generators.Identity));
    this.Property(x => x.Description, e =>e.NotNullable(true));
    this.ManyToOne(x => x.Group, e => e.Column("GroupId"));
}

public GroupMapping()
{
    this.Table("[Group]");
    this.Schema("[RSS]");
    this.Id(x => x.Id, e => e.Generator(Generators.Identity));
    this.Property(x => x.Name, e => e.NotNullable(true));
    this.Property(x => x.Icon, e => e.NotNullable(false));
    this.Bag(x => x.Categories, mapper => mapper.Key(e => e.Column("GroupId")), relation => relation.OneToMany());
    }
```

The problem is when a try to get the group list

```
var groupList = session.Query<Group>()
        .Fetch(x => x.Categories)
        .Take(10)
        .ToList();
```

the groupList above end up with duplicated items, like

---

1. Group 1

   - Category A
   - Category B
   - Category C
2. Group 1

   - Category A
   - Category B
   - Category C
3. Group 1

   - Category A
   - Category B
   - Category C

---

And the list should be

---

1. Group 1

   - Category A
   - Category B
   - Category C
2. Group 2

   - Category D
   - Category E
   - Category F

---

something missing in code ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a cartesian product issue with the query above.

### Option 1

I have recently changed my mappings to avoid this by mapping collections as sets instead of bags.

This type of change would require you to define your collections like:

```
public virtual ISet<Category> Categories { get; set; }
```

And your mappings would change to (this is a guess as I use FNH and not mapping by code):

```
this.Set(...)
```

If you change your mappings to this you must then override the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` functions for your entities.  I strongly recommend using a base class to do this so you don't have to repeat these functions in every entity you have.  Here is a great starting point for this base class:

https://github.com/nhibernate/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity/blob/master/source/NHibernate.AspNet.Identity/DomainModel/EntityWithTypedId.cs

### Option 2

You can query the items differently to avoid the cartesian product like described in this article:

[Fighting cartesian product (x-join) when using NHibernate 3.0.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266180/fighting-cartesian-product-x-join-when-using-nhibernate-3-0-0)